# How to export Structure from WeBI report

Tags: business-objects, webi

I want to get the technical name of the fields that are used in the WeBI report. Is there a way to export the structure of my report to retrieve the details.

Thanks
Niki

Answer (score 0):

Check this out (SAP access required)...

https://me.sap.com/notes/0002399962

I don't know if that will get you down to the report level details you want. To do that I think you will need a to use the SDK or a third party tool (which is built on the SDK).